# Can I register a custom intent both in manifest (for api < 27) and at runtime (for API 27+)?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

As the question goes, can I have both manifest and runtime custom intent registration? Or is it forbidden or frowned upon? 
My app targets both API 21 and API27+, and I prefer not to have 2 manifests with and without a registered intent, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may register the same `BroadcastReceiver` both in the Manifest and at runtime, but this may not make sense.

In order to make your app work both on API 21 and the latest Android version I suggest you remove your Manifest-declared receiver and register it at runtime, for example in a foreground service or in an `Activity` (really depends on what you are trying to achieve). This way you will receive the `Intent` regardless of your Android version.

BTW, if you keep the Manifest-declared receiver and also register the `BroadcastReceiver` at runtime the receiver will be called twice when a matching broadcast is sent.

Comment: Are you sure it will be called twice? This is not a behavior I am experiencing just now. Also, if I am no registering it in the manifest for API21, I am not getting it.

Comment: I tested it on API 24 (before the behaviour changes), and if I registered the same receiver once in the Manifest and once in an Activity, it would be triggered twice (as long as the activity was running).